# Trouble working with char* in C++, in a class, which is public cannot access a char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am pretty new to C++, and here is my code. I want help with string_1::tolower() and toupper(). There may be a minor bug, but I could not find it.
I am trying to build a class for strings, with overloaded operators and functions. 
The program runs well till the "last string with tolower", and then as soon as we access the string(char) pointer in the class, it becomes irresponsive. It exits with error code, normally we get in exceeding memory allocation/indefinite loop.
 Please go through the code and help me.

```
   #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
class string_1{
    public:
        char *str;

        string_1();
        string_1(int i);
        void display(); 
        string_1 operator +(string_1 b);
    //  string_1 operator =(string_1  b);
        string_1 operator =(char *b);
    //  string_1& operator +=(string_1 const &b);
        int length();
        void tolower();
        void toupper();


};
void string_1::tolower()
{
    char offset='a'-'A';
    char *temp=str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        if(*temp>='A'&&*temp<='Z')
        {
            (*temp)+=offset;
        }
        temp++;
    }
    return;


}
void string_1::toupper()
{
    char offset=32;
    char *temp=str;
    cout<<str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        if(*temp>='a'&&*temp<='z')
        {
            cout<<"IN\t"<<*temp;
            *temp=*temp+offset;
        }
        temp++; 
    }


}

void string_1::display()
{
    char *temp=str;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
string_1::string_1()
{
    str=new char[10];
//  cout<<"In zero argument constructor\n";
}
string_1::string_1(int i)
{
    str=new char[i];
    //cout<<"In 1 arg constructor,made string_1 of "<<i<<endl;

}

int string_1::length()
{
    int len=0;
    char *temp=str;
    while(*temp++!='\0') len++;
    return len;
}
string_1 string_1::operator +(string_1 b)
{
    int len1,len2;

     char *temp,*b_str,*ret_str;
     b_str=b.str;
    temp=str;
    len1=length();
    len2=b.length();
    len1=len1+len2+1;
    cout<<"\n Debug: Lengths L1,L2:"<<len1<<" l2:"<<len2;

    string_1 ret(len1);
    ret_str=ret.str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        *ret_str=*temp;
        ret_str++;
        temp++;
    }
    while(*b_str!='\0')
    {
        *ret_str=*b_str;
        b_str++;
        ret_str++;
    }
    *ret_str='\0';

    // We have to make sure we do not mess up with str
    return ret;
}

string_1 string_1::operator =(char *b)
{
    delete[] str;
    str=b;
    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

string_1 a(20),b,c,d,e;
a="Hello world !!!";
b="Hello C++";
c=a+b;
d="ABcd12!+]<>WxyZ";
cout.setf(ios::unitbuf);
cout<<"Displaying strings a,b,c,d"<<endl;
a.display();b.display();c.display();d.display();
cout<<"last string with tolower"<<endl;
//e=d;
d.tolower();d.display();
cout<<"last string with toupper"<<endl;
d.toupper();
d.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check your assignment and copy constructor

Comment: one issue I see is in `string_1 string_1::operator =(char *b)`.  You allocate `str` as an array, e.g.: `str=new char[10];`, but in this function, you do not delete array.  You should: `delete [] str` for arrays.

Comment: You do not have a copy constructor.  Your operator + and = will return a bit copy.  Make a: `string_1(const string_1 & passed)` copy constructor.  Quite likely, this is your problem because the `str` will be deleted and your while loops will be iterating over bogus memory.  As a rule of thumb, you should always define a copy constructor and an assignment operator - at least until you better understand what it means to not define them.

Comment: You need a destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help !!!
I got some important knowledge with your answers. Cant +1 anyone, cause have sufficient rep.
I somehow managed to tweak the code.
What I done is: improved = operator to strcpy the string. That was the problem . I guess we cant edit const strings in any case.  plus added +=.
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;
    /* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
    class string_1{
        public:
            char *str;

```
        string_1();
        string_1(int i);
    string_1( string_1 &b);

        void display(); 
        string_1 operator +(string_1 b);
    //  string_1 operator =(string_1  b);
        string_1& operator =(const char *b);
        string_1 operator +=(string_1 b);
        int length();
        void tolower();
        void toupper();


};

string_1::string_1(string_1 &b)
{
    str=b.str;

}
void string_1::tolower()
{
    char offset='a'-'A';
    char *temp=str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        if(*temp>='A'&&*temp<='Z')
        {
            (*temp)+=offset;
        }
        temp++;
    }
    return;


}
void string_1::toupper()
{
    char offset=32;
    char *temp;
    temp=str;
//  cout<<str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        if(*temp>='a'&&*temp<='z')
        {
        //  cout<<"IN\t";
            *temp=*temp-offset;
        //  cout<<"OUT";
        }
        temp++; 
    }


}

void string_1::display()
{
    char *temp=str;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
string_1::string_1()
{
    str=new char[10];
//  cout<<"In zero argument constructor\n";
}
string_1::string_1(int i)
{
    str=new char[i];
    //cout<<"In 1 arg constructor,made string_1 of "<<i<<endl;

}

int string_1::length()
{
    int len=0;
    char *temp=str;
    while(*temp++!='\0') len++;
    return len;
}
string_1 string_1::operator +(string_1 b)
{
    int len1,len2;

     char *temp,*b_str,*ret_str;
     b_str=b.str;
    temp=str;
    len1=length();
    len2=b.length();
    len1=len1+len2+1;
    cout<<"\n Debug: Lengths L1,L2:"<<len1<<" l2:"<<len2;

    string_1 ret(len1);
    ret_str=ret.str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        *ret_str=*temp;
        ret_str++;
        temp++;
    }
    while(*b_str!='\0')
    {
        *ret_str=*b_str;
        b_str++;
        ret_str++;
    }
    *ret_str='\0';

    // We have to make sure we do not mess up with str
    return ret;
}
string_1 string_1::operator +=(string_1 b)
{
    int len,len2;
    len=strlen(str);
    len2=strlen(b.str);
    len=len+len2+1;
    char *ret,*temp1,*bb;
    ret=new char[len];
    temp1=ret;
    char *temp=str;
    while(*temp!='\0')
    {
        *temp1++=*temp++;
    }
    delete[] str;
    bb=b.str;
    while(*bb!='\0')
    {
        *temp1++=*bb++;
    }
    *temp1='\0';
    str=ret;
    return *this;
}

string_1& string_1::operator =(const char *b)
{
    delete[] str;
    int len=strlen(b);

    str=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str,b);


    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

string_1 a(20),b,c,d,e;
a="Hello world !!!";
b="Hello C++";
c=a+b;
d="ABcd12!+]<>WxyZ";
cout.setf(ios::unitbuf);
cout<<"Displaying strings a,b,c,d"<<endl;
a.display();
b.display();
c.display();
d.display(); 
//c=d;
cout<<"last string with tolower"<<endl;

d.tolower();
d.display();
cout<<"last string with toupper"<<endl;
d.toupper();
d.display();
cout<<"Output of c+=d; ::";
c+=d;
c.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work as it is, you could do the following in your =operator:

```
string_1 string_1::operator =(char *b)
{
    strcpy(str, b);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: he can get bufferoverflow on your case.so first he should allocate enough memory then copy.Plus it was already commented he should reimplemet his code considering rule of three

Answer (score 0):

The string `d="ABcd12!+]<>WxyZ"` won't fit in the default size of 10 - it needs at least 17 chars. For a quick fix, try increasing the size of the allocated `str` in your constructor.

BTW, your class should probably keep (and check) the allocated size so you won't overflow your `str` buffer.

Comment: But , I suppose d="ABcd12!+]<>WxyZ"; will invoke the overloaded operator =, in which I delete previous string and just assign address of incoming string to the pointer in the class. 
Hence , I think increasing str[] will not have any effects. I think the zero argument constructor only gets called when I declare the object.